# Alexa: Elicit slots after DelegateDirective

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, voice

I am running into issues when trying to elicit a slot after delegating to a new intent.

I have an intent called EnterPIN which handles conversation flow surrounding PIN entry for account linking. It checks if they have account linked, and if so asks for PIN, and otherwise tells them how to account link.

The desired result would be to delegate to this intent any time PIN is required, and pass along the previous intent so it can return after authentication is done.

When I delegate to EnterPIN, I am not able to fill the PIN slot even after eliciting the slot on the current intent. However, when I directly invoke the EnterPIN intent through an utterance like 'sign me in' then the slot's are elicited correctly and it accepts my PIN on the next request.

CallContactCentre.js (snippet):

```
  return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .addDelegateDirective({name: 'EnterPIN', slots: { 
      "OBFUSCATE_PIN": {
        "name": "OBFUSCATE_PIN",
          "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
       }
    }})
    .withShouldEndSession(false)
    .getResponse();
```

EnterPIN.js:

```
module.exports = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    const sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();

    console.log('request.intent', request.intent);

    return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && request.intent.name === 'EnterPIN'
      && request.intent.slots
      && request.intent.slots.OBFUSCATE_PIN
      && request.intent.slots.OBFUSCATE_PIN.value === undefined
      && handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes().PIN === undefined
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const requestAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();
    const sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();

    if(handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.user.accessToken !== undefined) {
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak('You have account linked. Please enter your PIN code')
        .reprompt(requestAttributes.t('PROMPT'))
        .addElicitSlotDirective('OBFUSCATE_PIN')
        .withShouldEndSession(false)
        .getResponse();
    } else {
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak('You have not account linked. Please find this skill in the Alexa directory and enable account linking')
        .reprompt(requestAttributes.t('PROMPT'))
        .addElicitSlotDirective('OBFUSCATE_PIN')
        .withShouldEndSession(false)
        .getResponse();
    }    
  },
};
```

Direct invocation:

```
requestEnvelope.request.intent = { name: 'EnterPIN', confirmationStatus: 'NONE',
  slots: { 
    OBFUSCATE_PIN: { 
      name: 'OBFUSCATE_PIN',
      value: '1234',
      confirmationStatus: 'NONE',
      source: 'USER' 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Delegate Directive:

```
requestEnvelope.request.intent = { name: 'EnterPIN', confirmationStatus: 'NONE',
  slots: { 
    OBFUSCATE_PIN: { 
      name: 'OBFUSCATE_PIN',
      confirmationStatus: 'NONE',
      source: 'USER' 
    } 
  } 
}
```

As you can see, we get a value for OBFUSCATE_PIN when going through the direct invocation, but when reaching the intent from a delegate directive, the value is not being set.

Any information that could lead to the fix of this issue is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to include "value" when you create the new intent in delegateDirective.

```
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .addDelegateDirective({name: 'EnterPIN', slots: { 
      "OBFUSCATE_PIN": {
        "name": "OBFUSCATE_PIN",
        "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
        "value": ""      <-----------
       }
    }})
    .withShouldEndSession(false)
    .getResponse();
```